# How to check multiline text with regex after first match and only before the second one

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching, pcre

I'm trying to find needed log in a pretty big log file(let's say 250 mb).
Every single log starts with

> YYYY-MM-DD time:

Next goes some *one or multiline text* that **I want to match**

And finally ends with a newline and new DateTime pattern.

The question is how to match the text inside a log if it is *multiline and only before the next log*.
**The order of matching values is unknown** as well as the line of them.

I have tried next solution

```
grep -Pzio '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} timePattern)(?=[\s\S]*?Value1)(?=[\s\S]*?Value2)(?=[\s\S]*?Value3)[\s\S]*?(?=(\n\1|\Z)' file.log
```

But it comes to overhead PCRE limit even with ungreedy `[\s\S]*?` or simply gets previous unmatched log and includes lots of other logs in `[\s\S]*` before it finally *finds all three values to match before the first capturing group* and just gives me back huge text.

So the only difficulty is multiline I think here.
Will appreciate any help!

EDIT 0: I need to find only one log that has all the values that I'm trying to match.

EDIT 1: Example

```
2018-02-09 03:52:46,347 Activity=SomeAct
@Request=<S:Body><S:RQ><S:Info><S:Key><S:First>Value1</S:First><S:Second>Value2</S:Second></S:Key></S:Info></S:RQ></S:Body>
@Response=<SOAP-ENV:Body><S:RS><S:StatusCode>FAILURE</S:StatusCode></S:RS></SOAP-ENV:Body>
2018-02-09 03:52:51,377 Activity=SomeAct
@Request=<S:Body><S:RQ><S:Info><S:Key><S:First>Value1</S:First><S:Second>Value2</S:Second></S:Key></S:Info></S:RQ></S:Body>
@Response=<SOAP-ENV:Body><S:RS><S:StatusCode>SUCCESSFUL</S:StatusCode></S:RS></SOAP-ENV:Body>
2018-02-09 03:52:52,112 Activity=SomeAct
@Response=<SOAP-ENV:Body><S:RS><S:StatusCode>FAILURE</S:StatusCode></S:RS></SOAP-ENV:Body>
@Request=<S:Body><S:RQ><S:Info><S:Key><S:First>Value1</S:First><S:Second>Value3</S:Second></S:Key></S:Info></S:RQ></S:Body>
```

I need to get only the record with value1 and value2 in SUCCESFULL status. **BUT** it is not necessary that response is after request or `<first>` goes before `<second>` or RS\RQ are only one lines.

Comment: would be great if you include some examples in the question.

Comment: The `\1` in your attempt will require the *same* date as the first capturing parenthesis to occur after the match; that can't be right (at least not in the general case)?

Comment: Also `\{d2}` is wrong but maybe that's just a transcription error, and not in your actual code?

Comment: Even in spite of the non-greedy quantifier, your regex could straddle record boundaries. The regex enigine will do its darndest to find a way to match your pattern, and if it has to cross a date stamp after a newline to find a match, that's still permitted by greedy matching. I don't think there is a good way to do this with `pcregrep` really.

Comment: Ohh, sure `\{d2}` is just a misprint - edited - thank you. Regarding `\1` - as it is date on start of newline it's okay. I'm using named pattern now `(?P<datetime>^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` and it gives exactly the same result as `\1`. Still I'm not able to tell the engine to stop matching when it meets it once again :(

Comment: And great thanks for the answer, will look into another ways.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to find but a common approach is to use Awk with a custom record separator so that a record can be multiple lines.  Or you can collect the records manually:

```
awk '/^YYYY-MM-DD time: / { if (seen1 && seen2 && seen3) print rec;
        seen1 = seen2 = seen3 = 0; rec = "" }
    { rec = (rec ? rec "\n" $0 : $0 }
    /Value1/ { seen1++ }
    /Value2/ { seen2++ }
    /Value3/ { seen3++ }
    END { if (seen1 && seen2) print rec; }' file
```

This collects into `rec` the lines we have seen since the previous separator, and when we see a new separator, we print the previous value from `rec` before starting over if all the "seen" flags are set, indicating that we have matched all the regexes with the text in the current `rec`.

A common omission is forgetting to also do this in the `END` block, when we reach the end of the file.

Comment: I've tried this solution adopting it to my values like `awk '/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ { if (seen1 && seen2) print rec; seen1 = seen2 = 0; rec = "" } { rec = (rec ? rec "\n" $0 : $0) } /234E6741-3BA8-4F90-B85F-33D1C7E61E7F/ { seen1++ } /4d444f2f-2f20-48ab-b708-283e36771c61/ { seen2++ } END { if (seen1 && seen2) print rec; }' log.log` but after 30+ minutes of execution - it is still in an unfinished state. Perhaps, I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: `\d` is not available in Awk regex; you need `[0-9]`. The rest looks reasonable, by quick glance.

Comment: 300 minutes to read 250G is already an indication that you have something going seriously wrong. The script never finds a terminator so it ends up reading everything into memory, more and more slowly as it starts to swap.